# C#: simple Multiple-inheritance / mixin replacement?

Tags: c#

I have a class from an external library which I need to extend into antoher class. Also the extensions should remain reusable, as I need them also to be implemented in other places.

As neither mixins nor multiple inheritance are supported in C#, whats the *common way* to solve this?

```
namespace ExtLib
{
    public class Properties
    {
        public virtual int fieldN { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MyLib
{
    public class Extensions
    {
        public virtual int fieldM { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        // needs to have all fields from ExtLib.Properties AND MyLib.Extensions
    }

    public class MyOtherModel
    {
        // needs to have all fields from MyLib.Extensions,
        // MyLib.Extensions should be reusable
    }
}
```

---

I know a solution could be an interface `IExtensions`, however this leads to alot of duplication as the number of the fields of `Extensions` and `Properties` are quite high (and in the development phase they change alot).

---

Are there any best practices?

Comment: extension methods: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: To be clear: extension methods will only help you if you have very complex field implementations that need to be shared across types and wrapped in those fields. If the main purpose of using multiple inheritance in this scenario is just to be able to update one object without updating all of the other objects that inherit from it, then you are either stuck inheriting from one object or using multiple interfaces to minimize that pain.

Comment: Thanks! The purpose was just to extend an existing class and re-use the extension (fields) in other places. So extension-methods aren't, as you said, a suitable fit for my need.

Answer (score 6):

How about you just aggregate instances of these classes into `MyModel`?

```
public class MyModel
{
    private Properties _properties;
    private Extensions _ extensions;

    public MyModel(Properties properties, Extensions extensions)
    {
        _properties = properties;
        _extensions = extensions;
    }

    public Properties Prop
    {
        get { return _properties; }
    }

    public Extensions Ext
    {
        get { return _extensions; }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can of course get rid of manual backing fields and use auto-implemented properties with a public getter and private setter.

All changes to `Properties` and `Extensions` will be automatically reflected in `MyModel`. Aggregation is a common way of using design patterns in an object oriented manner as opposed to class manner, which regularly uses multiple inheritance.

As for polymorphism issues, you can create a derived class, override any behavior you want and pass an instance of that class into the constructor.

Comment: And how can we use `virtual` / `override` in this case ?

Comment: @Fabjan what problem is virtual/override going to solve?

Comment: @moarboilerplate polymorphism problem i guess, OP has virtual methods (that can possibly be overridden) and he was asking about `inheritance` rather than simple aggregation

Comment: @Fabjan Well, C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance, so unless these two classes share a common base class, we are practically screwed... I am not sure that there is a nice solution to OP's problem. Also, the question was about *inheritance replacement*.

Comment: I'm new to C#, so I don't know where I have *methods* exactly? Those just supposed to be *fields* (to be more precise, I'm working with MVC and the model's properties/fields in the external library were all declared `virtual`, so I adapted this). Thanks for your answer, but this is almost the same as the `interface`-solution so far, except that it does not have compile-time checks.

Comment: @Serthy Well in this case most likely what you're trying to do is to create a ViewModel out of two models and aggregation (and therefore this answer) is probably the best you can use here... And by the way `get;` and `set;` are actually methods that are implemented automatically by compiler (it's so called auto implemented properties)

Comment: I agree, in C#, this delegation model is the best way to achieve these goals.

Comment: Thanks! So I'm required to use either aggregation (or Interfaces in other places) and kind of duplicate my code. At least now I know that there's no better way then (which is unfortunate, as it looked like you can almost do everything in C# pretty easily)

Comment: @Serthy Yes. Although you can reduce duplication at the cost of increased complexity by creating an abstract class that aggregates these objects and maps them to the fields, and then inherit from that class.

Comment: @moarboilerplate [like this](http://pastebin.com/S4xYaRYv)? If so, where do I reduce duplication then?

Comment: @Serthy Looks correct. You reduce duplication when you have multiple models, but if you only have one model, then yes, you wouldn't need that abstract class. The reduction in duplication would come from when Extensions changes--you only have to update the abstract class.

Comment: @Kapol I think showing auto properties would be good rather than making manual backing fields. It's less repetitive, more compact, and easier to read, which seems to be what the question's going after. (I'm referring to `public Properties Prop { get; private set; }`.)

Comment: @31eee384 Thanks for the comment, I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create an abstract class that is derived from ExtLib, then derive MyProject from your abstract class

```
namespace ExtLib
{
    public class Properties
    {
        public virtual int fieldN1 { get; set; }
        public virtual int fieldN2 { get; set; }
        public virtual int fieldN3 { get; set; }
        public virtual int fieldN4 { get; set; }
        public virtual int fieldN5 { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MyLib
{
    abstract class Extensions : Properties
    {
        public virtual int fieldM1 { get; set; }
        public virtual int fieldM2 { get; set; }
        public virtual int fieldM3 { get; set; }
        public virtual int fieldM4 { get; set; }
        public virtual int fieldM5 { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyModel : Extensions
    {
        // contains all fields from ExtLib.Properties AND MyLib.Extensions
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution provided 2 things: 1) it makes logical sense for Extensions to inherit from Properties (it probably does) and 2) MyModel contains fields in addition to those provided by the abstract class, otherwise it doesn't even make sense to abstract Extensions

Comment: @moarboilerplate - Whether class Extensions is abstract or not depends on the actual details here, that we don't need to go into.  I assume Serthy is smart enough to make that decision for himself.  I actually thought your idea, extension methods, deserved more exploring.

Comment: @JoeH ah, by abstract I meant putting Extensions in a reusable layer of abstraction (be it an abstract or concrete class). As for extension methods, adding extension methods to interface types works well when the benefits of the ad hoc functionality outweighs the drawbacks of having to implement interface fields on your concrete implementations. It's a handy trick but like anything can be abused.

Comment: Thanks for the code! he problem here is that `Extensions` now is drived from `Properties`, so I cannot reuse this class without polluting other classes that use the fields of `Extension`

Comment: @Serthy - I'm not sure what you mean by "polluting other classes", I just thought you needed to inherit functionality.  I guess there are some details to your requirements that were not clear to me from your original question.  Your own comment said "needs to have all fields".  :-(

Comment: I was looking for a way in C# to extend a class by a reusable other class. If my reusable class  inherits from something, its polluted by the base classes properties. So I cannot reuse this extension-class for other stuff, as for now its inheriting unwanted things.

Comment: @Serthy - got it...  with these additional requirements (after your edit), my solution wouldn't work for you.  Thanks